# A person is trapped in a room with 4 doors. What is the expected number of days

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability

A person is trapped in a room with 4 doors. The first door leads to a passage that returns him to the room after 2 days; the second also returns him to the room, after 4 days. The third door takes him to freedom after 1 day.  Finally, the fourth door takes him back to the room after 5 days.  Assuming he chooses between unexplored doors at random, what is the expected number of days to freedom?  (The prisoner can mark or remember which doors he's already chosen, so he never chooses the same door twice.)

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  In this case, where we expect states to recur many times before the end, it is natural to use Markov techniques.  Here it suffices to just look at the possible states and solve a simple system of linear equations.

Comment: "The third takes him to freedom after 1 day and the third also takes him to the room after 5 days." You meant "fourth" instead of "third" somewhere here right?

Comment: Note:  on rereading I see that I missed the bit where the prisoner can mark the doors.  That makes the problem considerably simpler, as the states can not recur.

Comment: I'm concerned. Why are you keeping someone trapped prisoner for multiple days? Why are we helping you with your math rather than helping your prisoner with their escape?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: There is a $50\%$ chance that any given returning door will be chosen  before the escaping door.

Answer (score 0):

"The prisoner can mark or remember which doors he's already chosen, so he never chooses the same door twice."

This is crucial. There are only 24 ways of choosing 4 doors in some order and here there are even less scenarios since as soon as the prisoner picks door 3 the choosing stops. So you can make a list of all scenarios (given that there are less than 24 this is not so much work).

Next for each scenario compute the probability (see example below) and the number of days it costs. Then add 'probability times time' over all scenario's as in the definition of expectation.

Example: scenario Door 1 first, then Door 2 second then door 3 third. This has probability 1/4 times 1/3 times 1/2 = 1/24 because at first Door 1 has 1/4 probability of being chosen from four options, then door 2 has 1/3 probability of being chosen from 3 options and finally door 3 has 1/3 probability of being chosen from the two remaining options. Also this scenario takes 2 + 4 + 1 = 7 days.

Now repeat this type of reasoning for all possible scenarios